# Expression steals from previously possessively matched characters

Tags: regex, pcre2

When using PCRE2 on regex101, group 1 in `\G(.*?(?:<[^>]*>|&[^;]*;)*+)*?(micro)` used on the string "<test><micro>" first matches the entire string (as expected) but (micro) then goes back and steals from the previously possessively matched content. Is this expected behavior? If so, why does it happen and how do i avoid it?

### What i tried:

- Putting the possessive modifier in different places (the .* at the start needs to be able to surrender characters)
- changing the regex to `\G(.*?(?:<[^>]*>|&[^;]*;)*+)*?(micro)?`, so that (micro) does not need to be matched. This succeeded in the test case above but when run against the string "micro", it failed to capture the string in group 2

### What i expect:

The regex should match everything up the a "micro" that is neither in <> nor in &; and capture it in group 1, then capture the micro in group 2.

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: "*first matches the entire string*" - what makes you think so? And more importantly, what are you trying to achieve? What is the environment, programming language, what is the expected action: replace, split, extract? I suspect a regex split with something like `(?|<([^>]*)>|&([^;]*);)` or `<[^>]*>|&([^;]*);|(micro)` could give a push in a good direction given the present state question.

Comment: For what you state under "what i expect" perhaps `(?:<[^<>]*>|&[^;]*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|((?:(?!<[^<>]*>|&[^;]*;).)*)(micro)` https://regex101.com/r/mXIf54/1

Comment: The goal was replacing "micro" with a different string when not an entity or in <>. Managed to do it with `\G(?:<[^>]*>|&[^; ]*;|.(?!icro))*+\Kmicro`. As i'm still curious about how my initial expression was able to steal from a possessive match, i'll leave this question open for now. Thanks to everyone for their help so far :)

Comment: @knorke3 In that case, I think this will also match what you want `(?:<[^>]*>|&[^; ]*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|micro` https://regex101.com/r/iG1sgT/1

Comment: That finally got me to understand how those control verbs work - thanks :)

Comment: @knorke3 Did that work out?